# Get feed level category (RSS)

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

I'm using SimplePie.

Is there a way to get the category of the feed? Right now I can only get the category at the item level of the feed. I know the feed normally has a category so is there anyway of retrieving this instead of the item level category?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [magpie rss](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/). It is one of the best feed parser. Its easy to use. You can actually configure everything in "5 mins".

Comment: Any idea how to do it with SimplePie?